# CellTable GWT doesn't show with a correctly height

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I've created a CellTable and works correctly but when I try to insert a new row with no element or white spaces looks like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: What is it that you want it to do? Why are you inserting empty rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just insert empty rows, height will be smaller than other rows. Use CSSResource and style the `tr` with proper height.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert an empty row, try inserting an HTML space inside it to initialize the height. Like `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks Abhijith Nagaraja. This is how my css looks now.

```
    .cellTable tbody td{
        height: 13px;
    }
```

Thanks a lot.